# Most efficient way of translating OID's in varBinds to MIB's

Tags: python-3.x, pysnmp

After my SNMP transaction is completed and results are stored in varBinds, I'd like to assign the MIB and the value to their own variables for further processing. When I try:

```
for x in varBinds
    print x
```

the OID is translated, however, I need the mib and the value to be assigned to individual variables when I try:

```
for oid, val in varBinds
    print oid, val
```

the OID is NOT translated. I have not figured out how to use `.loadMibs`, so I created a function to translate the OID that I invoke on `oid`:

`T = oid2mib(oid)`

```
def oid2mib(oid_str):

    oid_tuple = tuple(oid_str)
    mib_builder = builder.MibBuilder()
    compiler.addMibCompiler(mib_builder)
    mib_builder.loadModules('SNMPv2-MIB')
    mib_view = view.MibViewController(mib_builder)

    a, b, c = mib_view.getNodeName(oid_tuple)

    return b[-1] + '.' + '.'.join(map(str, c))
```

`print('Mib:%s Value:%s' % (T, val))`

This works and it translates my OID to MIB, but I am wondering if this is the most efficient way of achieving my desired result? Perhaps `.loadMibs` might be more efficient?

---

**UPDATE**

I Just tried the following,

```
for x in varBinds
    a, b = str(x).split('=')
    print(a.rstrip(), b.rstrip(), sep=' => ')
```

What are the pros and cons of this approach?

Answer (score 0):

Since you get your var-bindings translated in the first case, I suspect you have proper MIB loaded already.

So try this:

```
for oid, val in varBinds
    a, b = str(oid), str(val)
    print(a, b, sep=' => ')
```

You will need to call [loadMibs()](http://snmplabs.com/pysnmp/docs/api-reference.html#pysnmp.smi.rfc1902.ObjectIdentity.loadMibs) if you happen to run into the OID for which the MIB is not loaded.

Comment: Unfortunately, calling `str()` on `oid` and `val` did not work for me. 

I've reviewed the link, but I am still not sure how to use `loadMibs`. In the example above ( considering that the managed object I am polling is: `ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('SNMPv2-MIB', 'sysName', 0))`. Where do i call `loadMibs()`;  in my `getCmd()` or at the time of printing? Also, would the `modNames` that I pass to it only be `SNMPv2-MIB`?